# Monogame - Reload a sprite again

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm making a 2D game using Monogame. My character loads to the game fine, however when a user presses the <kbd>T</kbd> key, I want my character to reload again (As if the character has teleported.)

I have loaded the player content in the `LoadContent()` function like so:

```
player.Load(Content);
```

And in the `Draw()` function, I have tried to reload the character again when 'T' is pressed by doing:

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.T))
{
    player.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

and/or,

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.T))
{
    player.Load(Content);
}
```

but neither of these seem to work.

**My question is**, what is the correct way to successfully load the character again and where do I place this if statement?

**UPDATE:**

Here's my `player.Load()` method used in the player class:

```
public void Load (ContentManager Content)
{
    texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("danPlayer");    
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your player.Load() method?

Comment: I have updated the question showing my player.Load() method, it's very simple.

Comment: Right, so all that's doing is loading your texture from the file. The only time you'd call that again is if the texture changed or if you lost the reference to it somehow. Not for changing the character's position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a function for loading the character, which is good. Now:
**1)** The `Draw` function is meant for drawing. It's running (kind of) async from the game. All your game logic should be in the `Update` function.
**2)** You have to know how to check if a keyboard button is clicked, not if it is being held down, because this way, the character will `Load` as long as you are holding the 'T' key. No matter how fast you click 'T' key, the way you are doing it, you'll fire the `Load` function at least 2-3 times.
**3)** To check this, you'll need 2 variables holding the current and the last state of keyboard, and all your game logic should be in between the updates for new and old keyboard state. You could also create a simple function to check for `Click(Keys key)` and `Hold(Keys key)`

```
KeyboardSate ksNew, ksOld;
protected override void Update (GameTime gameTime)
{
    ksNew = KeyboardSate.GetState();

    *your logic here*

    if (Click(Keys.T))
        player.Load(Content);

    ksOld = ksNew;
}

private bool Click(Keys key)
{
    return ksNew.IsKeyDown(key) && ksOld.IsKeyUp(key);
}

private bool Hold(Keys key)
{
    return ksNew.IsKeyDown(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XNA the usual way, you don't want to call `Load` to reload the player. That function is usually used only to load the player's assets, primarily images.

Somewhere in your code there should be some method where you're initializing aspects of your player, such as position and perhaps some sort of state. What you do is you want to call that code whenever T is pressed.

I would refer to Monset's answer about how to go about getting your keypress. I would also recommend picking up a book on XNA, since most of your questions that I've seen on SO have been about things that are often covered in such books. The one I initially learned from was [Learning XNA](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013709.do), which seems like it might be your speed.